# Add Event to polymer paper submenu

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to redirect to different sections based on different sub-menu items. But I am iterating over an array and so I am not able to figure out how to redirect to different sections based on different array element selection.

Here's my code:

```
      <paper-submenu attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
      <paper-item class="menu-trigger"><iron-icon icon="icons:view-list"></iron-icon><span>Your Devices <span id="totalDevices"></span></span></paper-item>
      <paper-menu class="menu-content">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{devices}}" as="device" id="sub ">
        <paper-item><div>[[device.name]]</div></paper-item>
      </template>
      </paper-menu>
      </paper-submenu>
```

Say, there are 3 items in devices array. I want to redirect to section 1, 2 or 3 based on the items clicked. 
Thanks  !!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by redirecting based on sub-menu items? This is not very clear to me.

Comment: Before asking a question, you need to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look. I want that when user clicks different items in the sub-menu. He is redirected to different sections. How can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event listener to the items inside the dom-repeat template

```
<paper-item on-click="_onClickItem"><div>[[device.name]]</div></paper-item>
```

Polymer will add a `model` object on the event which you can access information about the items inside the template. Because you have the attribute `as="device"`, polymer will stick the device object onto `event.model.device`. You'll need to implement the `_onClickItem` function inside the element definition.

```
_onClickItem: function (event) {
    navigateToDevice(event.model.device)
}
```

Comment: Will the _onClickItem recognise which device array element is clicked. If yes, then how can I use it to redirect to different sections based on what device array element is clicked? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, because it is added inside the template. `event.model.device` will give you the exact instance you put in the `devices` array, corresponding to the one you clicked, so you can use it to determine which section you need to navigate to.

Comment: @Arnav any luck with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <paper-submenu>
          <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="menu-trigger">
            <iron-icon icon="supervisor-account"></iron-icon>Main menu
          </a>
          <paper-menu style="cursor: pointer;" class="menu-content sublist" class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
            <a data-route="menu-first" href="/menu/first">
              <iron-icon icon="verified-user"></iron-icon>
              <span>Menu First</span>
            </a>
          </paper-menu>
          <paper-menu style="cursor: pointer;" class="menu-content sublist" class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
            <a data-route="menu-second" href="/menu/second">
              <iron-icon icon="account-box"></iron-icon>
              <span>Menu Second</span>
            </a>
          </paper-menu>
        </paper-submenu>
```

menu-first and menu-second are your tags

```
   <section data-route="menu-first">
        <menu-first></menu-first>
   </section>
```

(If your are using Polymer Starter Kit, all you will have to do is add the urls to routing.html)

You should be able to add template repeat to get your list to be iterated within the paper-submenu.